# Cognito User Pool and AWS Gateway - How to configure a different set of user permissions with one app client?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am trying to understand the use of access tokens to authorize an API fronted by API Gateway.

My current understanding of the process is as follows:

- After setting up a Cognito User Pool, I can define a resource server and associated scopes (e.g. `https://wibble-api.com/read, https://wibble-api.com/full`).
- Then, I can select the allowed custom scopes for a user pool app client.
- In AWS Gateway, I can create a Cognito Authorizer to authorize incoming requests.
- For each AWS Gateway resource, I can go into the Method Request and select the Cognito Authorizer and determine which OAuth scopes are necessary in order to be able to execute the API method e.g. I can enter `https://wibble-api.com/read, https://wibble-api.com/full` to indicate that *either* of those two scopes are sufficient to be allowed to execute the API resource.
- When using the hosted UI, the `scope` parameter will include all of the allowed scopes configured for that app client, and the returned access token (if using implicit grant) will contain those scopes as part of the JWT.

What I don't understand is, I have what must be a very common scenario where I want to be able to give the read-only scope to, say, a user that hasn't paid for the service, and the full scope to a user that has paid. Yet it looks like I would need to have two separate app clients if I'm going to be using the Hosted UI, because there doesn't seem to be a way to return different scopes depending on, say, what group the user has been assigned, or some other metadata in their user profile such as department, etc. I won't know what sort of user they are until after they have been authenticated, but I still need to enter the exact `scope` when I am authenticating. Is there a solution for this, please?